# Measuring the non-diagonalness of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then, obviously $A$ is diagonal if and only if $\sum_{i\neq j}(a_{ij})^2 = 0$ with $i = 1,\ldots,n$ and $j = 1,\ldots,n$.

My question is what other ways are there to quantify the "non-diagonalness" of $A$? Clearly, measures like $\sum_{i\neq j}\lvert a_{ij}\rvert^k$ for $k > 0$ are trivial extensions of the what I wrote above. I would be very much interested in geometric characterizations of this idea. Clever numerical approaches are also appreciated.

Comment: I would look at any of the established matrix norms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm and apply them to matrix, where the diagonal has been replaced by all 0s. This would be for measuring the "magnitude" of non-diagonalness. If you wanted to measure "fractional" non-diagonalness, that might also be interesting. (Norm of the matrix with 0 diagonal, divided by norm of unedited matrix, perhaps?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix doesn't answer your question, but it's close enough that you might find it interesting.